# How to cover background-color to background-image without the latter transparent part

Tags: css, background-image, background-color

I want to implement css content for  [this effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaILz.png) :
But I dont know how to write right css code or maybe can't able to implement?
[Actual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvB7e.png)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="result.css" />
   <title>无标题文档</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color:black;" >
    <div class="_7_cursor_png"></div>
    <div class="_10_cursor_png"></div>
    <div class="board"></div>
    <div class="board2"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

```css
@keyframes k0 {
0% { opacity:0; }
0.0009999999% { opacity:1; }
99.99998% { opacity:1; }
100% { opacity:0; }
100% { opacity:0; }
}
._7_cursor_png { left:107px;
top:0px;
transform:rotate(0rad) scaleX(1) scaleY(1);
opacity:0.00;
background-color:#FFFF00;
height:240px;
width:240px;
animation:k0 4000001ms linear 0ms forwards;
background-image:url("cursor\.png");
background-blend-mode:multiply;
position:fixed; }
@keyframes k1 {
0% { opacity:0; }
0.0009999999% { opacity:1; }
99.99998% { opacity:1; }
100% { opacity:0; }
100% { opacity:0; }
}
._10_cursor_png { left:427px;
top:240px;
transform:rotate(0rad) scaleX(1) scaleY(1);
opacity:1.00;
background-color:#FFFFFF;
height:240px;
width:240px;
animation:k1 4000001ms linear 0ms forwards;
background-image:url("cursor\.png");
background-blend-mode:multiply;
position:fixed; }
.board { top:480px;
left:0px;
width:3000px;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
height:3000px;
position:fixed;
background-color:#000000; }
.board2 { left:854px;
top:0px;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
width:3000px;
height:3000px;
position:fixed;
background-color:#000000; }
```

I just want to change background image color but skip these transparent pixels , so I think it should provide css property or something I could use.

Comment: background-color: transparent;

Comment: put your code please